# .htaccess retorna erro 500 ao invés de 404

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, servidor

Meu arquivo .htaccess parece estar ok, mas, se tentarmos acessar uma página que não existe, ao invés de receber a resposta de erro 404, recebo a resposta de erro 500.

Este é o código atual:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove o www e força o https
# funciona muito bem
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Deveria carregar as páginas amigáveis de erros, mas não funciona!!!!
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /e404.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /e500.php [L]

# Permite carregar as páginas sem a extensão .php, também está OK.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema trocando

```
# Permite carregar as páginas sem a extensão .php, também está OK.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

por

```
#permite carregar as páginas sem a extensão .php
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```